# Powershell Script copy file to another servers folder having credentials

Tags: powershell, powershell-3.0, powershell-4.0

I'm new to powershell script .
I'm working in a company, got a task: there is a server lope1 where resides some pdf files under many folders , and another server is lope2, task is copy all PDF files(all PDF including in sub folders also ) from server's lope1 SD folder to server's lope2 ms folder and lope2 server having credentials uname abc and password is pass .

Please help .

Thanks in advance.

Comment: What have you tried so far? You should be aware SO is not a code writing service. Also, depending on your needs copy jobs can usually be handled by other utilities like robocopy.

Comment: I have tried little bit but not able to add credentials required for lope2 server :    Copy-Item "C:\SD" -Destination "\\lope2\C$\ms" -Recurse

Answer (score 0):

If you use New-PSDrive to mount the drive with the needed credentials you would be able to use Copy-Item.

Comment: I'm beginner of powershell, Could you please elaborate it or write the sample script code :)

Comment: New-PSDrive -Name X -PSProvider FileSystem -Root \\lope2\FolderName -Credential Domain\UserName -Persist